# Slideshow content's SEO development

Tags: html, seo

I have a thought about a slideshow's seo question.

For the content which has not been showed by the slideshow yet, I treat them as hidden div. And they would be indexed but ccould be frowned upon by seach engine (Google of course...) if the content is hiding/showing content for SEO reasons.

Also, some people say actually what Google sees should be what the user sees when clicking the link.

However, what if the keyword is locating at the not showing parts at that moment, will those keyword or description be detected by search engine or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engines see whatever you put in your HTML. Even if the content is hidden by CSS it is crawled and indexed by them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it means i can't use some jquery plugins...